# How to find element by xpath from iframe in QTP

Tags: javascript, xpath, qtp

I try to set value in `<input type="file" name="file007">` in QTP
but this element is under `iframe` and it is unable to get it by xpath
from page:

```
<iframe id="file_007" src="javascript:''" style="position:absolute;width:0;height:0;border:0">
    #document
      <html>
       <head>
       </head>
          <body>
           <form action="/file/upload" method="POST" target="_self" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input name="files" type="text">
            <input type="hidden" name="name1" value="1">
            <input type="hidden" name="name2" value="2">
            <input type="hidden" name="name3" value="3">
            <input type="hidden" name="name4" value="4">
            <input type="hidden" name="name5" value="5">
            <input type="hidden" name="name6" value="6">
            <input type="hidden" name="name7" value="false">
            <input type="file" name="file007">
           </form>
    </body>
    </html>
    </iframe>
```

I found iframe by `//iframe[contains(@id, 'File')]` but elements inside `#documents` are not visible

How to find this element on page
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using XPath? It seems that QTP's default object identification should work fine for you.

```
 Browser("title:=.*").Page("title:=.*").Frame("html id:=file_007").WebFile("name:= file007").Set "C:\file.txt"
```

If you need to use XPath then I think that QTP only supports XPath's inside a document, so you need to identify the `Frame` (optionally by XPath) and then under it identify the element relative to its owner `Frame`.